# How to derive H2 transfer function (w -> z)?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

Give a general feedback system:
[image]

1. The dynamics of G:
   [image]
2. The dynamics of K:

   [image]
3. Suppose the A of the closed loop system；
   [image]

My questions is: **how to prove the transfer function** **T(s): w -> z**:

[image]

I know this is the form of C*inv(sI - A)*B + D, but **how to specify them?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'prove the transfer function' and 'how to specify them'? Are you asking how to show that $\hat{H}_{zw}(s) = \hat{T}(s)$? There is nothing involved other than a lot of tedious matrix manipulation (and using a formula for the inverse of a block diagonal matrix).

Comment: Yes. The main point I am confused is the approach. Combine which matrix, replace which matrix for example. I am confused in the signal flow.

Comment: In the above, you want to eliminate $u$, which you can do using $u=C_k x_k + D_k y$ and $y = C_2 x + D_{21} w + D_{22} u$. This will give a formula for $y$ (in terms of $w$, $x_k$ and $x$, which you then substitute back into the original equations.

Comment: I have a suspicion that $D_k=0$ in the above?

Comment: Yes Dk = 0. I am confused the last sentence. I get y = C2*x + D22*Ck*xk + D21*w and z = C1*x + D12*Ck*xk + D11*w. But how to include the inv(sI - bar(A))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes $D_k=0$:

The simplifying equations are $u=C_k x_k$ and $y=C_2 x + D_{21}w + D_{22}u = C_2 x + D_{22} C_k x_k + D_{21}w$.

Substituting this into the equations for $\dot{x}, \dot{x_k}$ and $z$ gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x} &=& A x + B_2 C_k x_k + B_1 w \\
\dot{x_k} &=& B_k C_2 x + (A_k +B_k D_{22} C_k)x_k  + B_k D_{21} w \\
z &=& C_1 x + D_{12} C_k x_k + D_{11} w
\end{eqnarray}
or in matrix notation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\bar{x}} &=& \begin{bmatrix} A & B_2 C_k \\
B_k C_2 & A_k +B_k D_{22} C_k \end{bmatrix} \bar{x} +
\begin{bmatrix} B_1 \\ B_k D_{21} \end{bmatrix} w \\
z &=& \begin{bmatrix} C_1 & D_{12} C_k \end{bmatrix} \bar{x} + D_{11} w
\end{eqnarray}
If $D_k = 0$, we have $\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -D_{22} & I \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ D_{22} & I \end{bmatrix}$, and so
$\begin{bmatrix} B_2 & 0 \\ 0 & B_k \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -D_{22} & I \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & C_k \\ C_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & B_2 C_k \\
B_k C_2 & B_k D_{22} C_k \end{bmatrix}$.
This gives the $\bar{A}$ above (adding $A,A_k$ in the formula for $\dot{\bar{x}}$, of course), from which we get the desired result.